# Contact Us Form not working under Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-controller

I started learning Zend so this is the link i followed for the contact us page -

My Zend Version - Zend Framework **v1.11.11**

http://www.tutorial-portal.com/tutorial/show/id/27

I created form using command line - `zf create form Contact` which successfully created folder `forms` under which `Contact.php` File. Code in `Contact.php` is as follows -

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Contact extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
        $this->setmethod('post');
        $this->setName('contact-form');

        $this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
                            'label' => 'Please enter your name',
                            'required' => true,
                         ));


        $this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
                            'label' => 'Please enter email address',
                            'required' => true,
                            'validators' => array('EmailAddress'),
                         ));

        $this->addElement('textarea', 'message', array(
                            'label' => 'Please enter your message',
                            'required' => true,
                            'validators' => array( array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array(0, 20) )
                         ));

        $this->addElement('captcha', 'captcha', array(
                            'label'      => 'Please enter the 5 letters displayed below:',
                            'required'   => true,
                            'captcha'    => array('captcha' => 'Figlet','wordLen' => 5,'timeout' => 300 )
                        ));                                      

        $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
                            'ignore'   => true,
                            'label'    => 'Send Message',
                        ));

        $this->addElement('hash', 'csrf', array(
                            'ignore' => true,
                        ));
    }               
}
```

Now I created a controller `ContactController.php` under `C:\xampp\htdocs\projectone\application\controllers`. Code in this controller goes like this -

```
<?php

class ContactController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
        //$form  = new Application_Form_Contact();
        //$this->view->form = $form;

    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
        // Create form instance
        $form = new Application_Form_Contact();

        /**
         * Get request
         */
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $post = $request->getPost(); // This contains the POST params

        /**
         * Check if form was sent
         */
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            /**
             * Check if form is valid
             */
            if ($form->isValid($post)) {
                // build message
                $message = 'From: ' . $post['name'] . chr(10) . 'Email: ' . $post['email'] . chr(10) . 'Message: ' . $post['message'];
                // send mail
                mail('contact@yourwebsite.com', 'contact: ' . $post['subject'], $message);
            }
        }

        // give form to view (needed in index.phtml file)
        $this->view->form = $form;

    }

}
```

Code in `index.phtml` under the folder structure  `C:\xampp\htdocs\projectone\application\views\scripts\contact` goes like this - echoing the code in php tags - `echo $this->form`

But this is not working at all :( really unable to locate what i am doing wrong.

Its only showing a blank page, and nothing even simple html content.

This is the URL im using, although rest controllers working fine -

```
http://localhost/projectone/public/contact
```

**PS**- Since I am a starter in Zend, I dont know where & how to look for Zend errors, let me know this also :)

Comment: check if the request reaches the controller... try putting a `die` statement in the controller

Comment: @NandakumarV Yes its working     public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
  // Create form instance
  die("Yes I am upto this point");  and its  reflecting the message  -> Yes I am upto this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After performing various heuristics, and checking the code at various levels I am able to debug my code. Problem actually was in this LOC -

**BUG** -

```
    $this->addElement('textarea', 'message', array(
                        'label' => 'Please enter your message',
                        'required' => true,
                        'validators' => array( array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array(0, 20) )
                     ));
```

**REMOVE**

```
'validators' => array( array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array(0, 20) )
```

and all goes well like a charm.